# I have two different process each one plot 2d point, I want the two process plot in the same figure?

Tags: wxmathplot

I have two different process each one plot 2d point, I want the two process plot in the same figure ?

Comment: Hi there Mehrez, could you explain the language/program you are trying to do this in with some code examples please.

Answer (score 0):

thanks 
i want to plot in the same matplotlib figure with python code 
using two process. the first one sleep(2) and the second one sleep(4)
thank you for help